# Pegar dados do banco e jogar em um select

Tags: angular

Aqui eu pego todos os funcionários da empresa (isso está correto, já faço em outra página da aplicação e puxa os dados certinho pelo .getFuncionarios)

```
setConsultores(){
     this.userService.getFuncionarios()
     .subscribe(response => {
       this.funcionarios = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response))
       this.allFuncionarios = this.funcionarios
         for (let funcionario of this.allFuncionarios) {
           this.allFuncionarios.push(funcionario)
         }
     })
}
```

Já no front, coloquei o select desta maneira

```
  <strong>Selecione um consultor para atender a empresa:</strong>
      <select class="form-control" name="consultorSelected" id="consultorSelected" (ngModelChange)="setConsultores()">
        <option *ngFor="let funcionario of allFuncionarios" value="{{funcionario.id}}">{{funcionario.nome}}</option>
      </select>
```

Porém, não está puxando esses valores, no caso só quero que apareça o nome do funcionário e que o valor seja o ID do funcionário selecionado.

Comment: Mas dá algum erro no console?

Comment: nenhum, tentei colocar a chamada da função setConsultores() na ngOnInit, aí ele acaba carregando a página muito e trava.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu HTML está com algumas coisas erradas. Tenta assim:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="funcionarioSelecionado">
    <option selected disabled>Selecione</option>
    <option *ngFor="let funcionario of funcionarios">
        {{funcionario.nome}}, {{funcionario.sobrenome}}
    </option>
</select>
```

E o ts:

```
funcionarioSelecionado: string;
funcionarios: any = [];

// Seu construtor

ngOnInit() {
    this.usuarioService.buscarTodos().subscribe(data => this.funcionarios = data);
}
```

Comment: Deu certo, valeu